# Build and render a form with inheritance classes in Symfony 6

Tags: php, forms, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have three classes (User, Professionel and Simple, where Professionel and Simple are the children of User). I use inheritance mapping like this:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name:"compte", type: "string")]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap(["professionnel"=>Professionel::class, "simple"=> Simple::class])]

class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(min:2, max:80)]
    private $email;
    
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 50)]
    private $typeCompte;
}

class Professionel extends User
{
    private $nameProfessionel;
    //getter setter
}

 class Simple extends User
{
    private $name;
    //getter setter
}
```

I have generated formtype for each entity and extended SimpleType and ProfessionelType like this:

```
class SimpleType extends UserFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
    
            ->add('name')

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Simple::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
class ProfessionelType extends UserFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nameProfessionel');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Professionel::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is whenever the user clicks on a radio button (Simple or Professionel), to only show the form that fits.
I have tried to build the form in the controller:

```
$types = [
            'parentForm' => UserFormType::class,
            'partForm' => SimpleType::class,
            'proForm' => ProfessionelType::class,
        ];
        $forms = [];
        foreach ($types as $type1) {
            $forms[] = $this->createForm($type1);
        }
```

but I have this error :

> Could not load type "App\Form\ChoiceType": class does not exist.

Comment: The error message strongly implies that you are using the ChoiceType some place without an use statement.

Comment: I have added the choice type class but I still, have the same error. It's appears on the controller with createForm method :  $forms[] = $this->createForm($type1);

Comment: You are not calling `parent::buildForm` on any of the subtypes, so I don't think your forms will come out as you expect. And besides class inheritance you can also use [symfony forms' inheritance mechanism](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-form-types-based-on-symfony-built-in-types) and skip all that.

Comment: Pretty sure that this is just a simple PHP problem.  Also confident that, like @msg suggests, you will have plenty of other problems once you get past this particular error.  In any event, consider updating your question with the UserFormType code including the `use` statements.

Comment: TBH, this error could be coming from _anywhere_ in the codebase. We are assuming that only these classes exist but we could be wrong. I don't think the `TypeGuesser` could be messing with the `use` statements, but instead of letting the form builder guess the form types itself, try passing explicit types. Otherwise, I'd start with a good ol' `grep -R ChoiceType src`  and see where that class is used.

Comment: Yeah thanks i had forgotten add use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType